# Why is TDS using so much bandwidth?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Playing on android:

I noticed my data plan had used almost 1g of data and I had no idea why.  I looked at my data usage and it stated that TDS had used almost all of this in just a couple of days.  Why does it need so much?

Comment: I don't know but I'm guessing it's saving the state to FB.  I think it also receives push updates/patches(?) for new floors/events, though, those should be small.  You could probably turn that off and have it not use data.  I play on my iPad so I can't do any testing. :(

Answer (score 1):

They started doing an online/offline storage thing, so I assume that's at least one reason the game is sucking down bandwidth.  I have stopped playing for the same reason, in addition to the new update and Imperial Mission nonsense.  I will periodically check in to try and get 100 levels, but I'm no longer playing on a daily basis.  Plus, it kept asking if I wanted to play the local version (9hrs 33mins ago) or the online version (9hrs 31mins ago).  That's just silly!